# Specify order after gather and spread

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to keep the order of the output variables the same as the order they were created in the mutate statement.  How do I accomplish this? It seems to be reordering alphabetically. Thanks!

```
df%>%
  mutate(
    twinkie= var1/60,
    peanut= var2/60,
    apple= var3/60,
    cheese= var4/60
  ) %>%
  group_by(store, associate)%>%
  summarise(
    twinkie=mean(twinkie),
    peanut = round(mean(peanut),
    apple = round(mean(apple),1),
    cheese = round(mean(cheese),1))
  %>%gather(Metric, value, -store, -associate)%>%spread(associate, value)
```

Comment: You could add: `%>% select(twinkie, peanut, apple, cheese)` Also, you could skip the `mutate` step by doing the `/60` calculations within `summarise`

Comment: @JuliaDills it seems to me that `summarise_at` would be the right choice for your case. May be if you can share `dput(head(df))` of your data we can suggest accordingly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Convert the gathered `Metric` to a factor with the desired ordering. After `gather`, the values of `Metric` will be in the order in which you created them. You can then use the `unique` function to set this order as the order of the levels in `Metric`. For example:

```
library(tidyverse)

# Fake data
set.seed(2)
df = replicate(4, rnorm(30)) %>% 
  as.tibble %>% 
  mutate(store=sample(LETTERS[1:3],30,replace=TRUE),
         associate=sample(letters[1:4],30,replace=TRUE))

df %>%
  group_by(store, associate) %>%
  summarise(
    twinkie=mean(V1/60),
    peanut = round(mean(V2/60)),
    apple = round(mean(V3/60),1),
    cheese = round(mean(V4/60),1)) %>%
  gather(Metric, value, -store, -associate) %>% 
  mutate(Metric = factor(Metric, levels=unique(Metric))) %>% 
  spread(associate, value)
```

> ```
>    store  Metric         a         b         c         d
> 1      A twinkie 0.1871809 0.1466679 0.1645085 0.1661182
> 2      A  peanut 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
> 3      A   apple 0.2000000 0.1000000 0.2000000 0.2000000
> 4      A  cheese 0.2000000 0.2000000 0.2000000 0.2000000
> 5      B twinkie 0.1635126 0.1865576 0.1823273 0.1857983
> 6      B  peanut 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
> 7      B   apple 0.2000000 0.1000000 0.2000000 0.1000000
> 8      B  cheese 0.2000000 0.2000000 0.2000000 0.2000000
> 9      C twinkie 0.1776549 0.1635294 0.1667490 0.1585236
> 10     C  peanut 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000
> 11     C   apple 0.2000000 0.2000000 0.1000000 0.2000000
> 12     C  cheese 0.2000000 0.2000000 0.2000000 0.2000000
> ```